# IE < 9 issue with <li> menu click delegation in jQuery 1.5.2

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm developing a plugin for a toolbar that generates a `<ul>` for a menu with each action as an `<li>` in this list:

```
  // HTML for the more dropdown
  var moreTemplate = [
    '<ul class="sooper-dooper-menu">',
      '<li class="favorite">Add to favorites</li>',
      '<li class="info">More info</li>',
      '<li class="comment">Comment</li>',
      '<li class="share">Share</li>',
    '</ul>'
  ].join('');
```

This menu appears when a user clicks the "more" button in my toolbar. To make this menu happen, I'm delegating clicks to the button with:

```
$(function() {
  $('body').delegate('.sooper-dooper-toolbar.more', 'click', function() {
    var $more = $(this),
        $menu = $(moreTemplate);

    // only one instance of a menu at a time
    if ($('.sooper-dooper-menu').length > 0) {
      $('.sooper-dooper-menu').remove();
    }

    $menu.attr('id', 'sooper-dooper-menu-' + $more.parent().data('sooper-dooper').id);
    $menu.css({top:$more.offset().top, left:$more.offset().left});
    $menu.bind('mouseleave click', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });

    $('body').append($menu);
    return false;
  });

  $('body').delegate('.sooper-dooper-menu li', 'click', function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id').substring(24),
      actions = {
        favorite: function() {_addFavorite(id);},
        info: function() {_info(id);},
        comment: function() {showCommentForm(id);},
        share: function() {showEmailForm(id);}
      };

    actions[$(this).attr('class')]();
    return false;
  });
});
```

I've tested this in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and IE, and it works across the board except for IE < 9. I've tried including ie-7.js for retrofitting compatiability, but no dice.

*Please don't comment that I need to upgrade jQuery (unless that is the only fix), it's not an option for me at this point.*

Comment: Is there a reason why this menu can't already exist on load and just be hidden?

Comment: Not particularly. I'll try that and see what happens. Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with removing the more  menu from the DOM. I guess IE doesn't hold on to the reference in jQuery when an element gets removed or something. I simply changed:

```
$menu.bind('mouseleave click', function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

to

```
$menu.bind('mouseleave click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

based on Jack's comment. Thanks!